# What event can check when document is ready or ajax is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very complex website with multiple queries, Ajax queries rendering JS, HTML, JSON, etc.

A lot of theses responses contains code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { doSomething('x'); });
```

I'm totally sure that `$(document).ready()` is only called when all my DOM is loaded, in non-remote queries.

But I have 2 types of Ajax calls too:

1. When my response renders HTML

   `$.get(url_html, {}, function(data) { $('#mycontainer').html(data); });`
2. When my response renders JS.

   `$.get(url_js, {})`

   The response of `url_js` is like `$('#mycontainer').html('foobar')`.

Theses two types of Ajax reponses contains this `$(document).ready()` method, but I don't know when this event is called. I want to declare an event, **contained in my HTML Ajax views**, who say "OK, I have finished to do do the JS ajax methods" (here, the simple `.html` function).

Does `$(document).ready()` can be OK for it ? Or is there something else ?

P.S. I insists on **contained in my HTML Ajax views**, because I don't know before call if I have to run the methods contained in response. If it was the case, I would have used `$.ajaxComplete`.

Regards

Comment: are you aware that ajax functions have a callback to run?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of your question is, but to be clear about the `ready` event - it fires on initial load of the page - `DOMReady`. If another `ready()` handler is attached after `DOMReady` has fired, it is immediately executed.

Comment: Your definition of "ready" may be missing something.  See this for a couple of other possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292117/how-to-use-ajax-to-detect-if-the-web-server-is-down-or-not-receiving-requests